# Switch between two versions of python in the same environment

Tags: python

I need to build a pipeline which was written in python 2.7. A few dependencies like matplotlib have been upgraded since then to work with Python 3.x, but the original pipeline code is incompatible with python 3.x syntax. While building, I am unable to use Python 2.7 as matplotlib and thereby mayavi refuse to be installed after that. And if I build everything using Python 3.x the final code does not execute because the code is incompatible with python 3.x.

The pipeline I need to run is https://github.com/aestrivex/ielu

Please help.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why exactly can't you use matplotlib in python 2.7? What is your Ubuntu version? are you using the OS default python, or a 3rd party installation such as anaconda?

Comment: @steeldriver looks like the repo mentioned wants to use anaconda

Comment: one possible course of action is to clone that repo and upgrade it to python3 then submit a pull request back to the repo ... however as @steeldriver suggests its probably easier to write your new code using python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyenv` to switch between python versions.

```
# Get Pyenv
curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash

# add pyenv to ~/.bashrc
echo -e "export PATH="/root/.pyenv/bin:$PATH" \n eval "$(pyenv init -)" \n eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)" " >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

# install python 3 via pyenv
pyenv install 3.5.6

# verify
pyenv versions

# pyenv local <version> : use this to set python version per directory.
# pyenv gloal <version> : use this to set python version globally.
```